# QGIS Nautical Chart Symbols for sector lights

Tags: qgis, symbology, print-composer

This is I know going to be of limited interest to many of you but I teach navigation and I am working on producing test questions and charts for assessing learners knowledge. My problem is solvable with post editing but as I am finding QGIS very versatile as I am learning it I think there may be another way to achieve this without needing post editing.

The effect I am looking for is this:

[image]

And in QGIS I have a layer with length of the vector lines and angle, and using the Vector Field marker symbol I get this:

[image]
This I am really impressed with and think I am probably asking to much to be able to either add colour bands as in image 1 or arrows between the lines labeled with the colour abbreviation.

One thought that I have is that perhaps there is some way to draw a radius and clip it to the sectors.

I am using Qgis Lyon and have a Mac so GIS alternatives are not easily possible.

Comment: How good are your python skills? You could potentially add your own symbol style using PyQGIS to exactly reproduce the symbol you are after.

Comment: I've never tried Python before but I will give it a go, I pretty fluent in PHP and a little C, is there an example set of code or tutorial you could suggest that I could learn from? I will google it also but your advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: I'm not aware of any online tutorials, but https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/building-mapping-applications-qgis has a great walkthrough on how this is done.

Comment: Great, I have made some progress but very basic so far. I have ordered the book you suggest and hopefully I will be enlightened by it. Thank you for your help.