# Creating sector lights in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, labeling, symbology, style

I'm using QGIS 2.18. I need to create sector lights for navigational purposes on a map.

I have the light sector data as fields giving becon_id, start degree, end degree and color in a shapefile with over 500 buoys, beacons and lighthouses that need to be shown on the map. For each beacon, there can be many rows, each describing one light sector (for instance a white sector)

The end result should look about like below: The light sectors in the right colors, with the color marked as the character in the color field (R G W), and dotted lines from 100m to 1000m from the buoy/beacon/lighthouse.

This should most likely be created as a ruled-based symbol, but needs some python I guess?

[image]

Here below is an example of the shapefile data for a lighthouse (unfortunately not the above one) which has a green sector between 114 and 154 degrees, a white sector between 154 and 168 degrees, a red sector between 168 and 237 degrees, a green sector between 237 and 314 degrees, a white sector between 314 and 320 degrees, a red sector between 320 and 337 degrees (for some reason, 0 is not north but south):

[image: shapefile table example]

Comment: related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170950/qgis-nautical-chart-symbols-for-sector-lights

Comment: Please, could you upload a sample dataset and edit your question by elaborating what exactly is the result you expect? In the attached image I only see a universe of symbols and colors.

Comment: Example data would help here. Do you have one feature per sector light, or one feature per buoy? Wedge Buffer plugin might help here, but how easy this is will depend on how your data is set up.

Comment: Hi @mgri and Steven , I added example data and tried to make the question clearer :), thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminDonner do you want a new layer with that simbology or a new ruled-based symbol? Both cases should be tricky to solve.

Comment: @mgri  only the visual end result is important, I need the light sectors in the right colors, with a color marked as the character in the color field (p v vi), and dotted lines from 100m to 1000m from the buoy/beacon/lighthouse. A rule based symbol is how I have supposed it must be made through.

Comment: @BenjaminDonner Thanks, but what do you mean with _dotted lines from 100m to 1000m_? Is the distance an additional variable? And, do you use a Geographic or Projected Reference System? I mean, do you work with degrees or meters/feet?

Comment: @mgri the lines are not a variable, but lines that should statically be shown as 900m long lines between the light sectors like in the image. Projected reference system.

Comment: @BenjaminDonner I found a possible solution. I'm sorry, but I can't write it by now: I'll do it in the next week!

Comment: Please, see my answer and let me know if this was what you were looking for!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**EDIT** I edited the answer for managing particular situations (due to specific angle values) and for not displaying the dotted lines when a round angle is defined.

---

I propose a solution by only recurring to rule-based symbology and labeling.

Before starting, I want to underline that I will focus the attention on the explanation of the minimal things to do for reproducing the desired result: this means that some other minor parameters (like sizes, widths and so on) should be easily adjusted by you for better fitting your needs.

Furthermore, **this solution only works if** you assume that `0` degree is North instead of South (if `0` is South, instead, it would be enough summing a `180` value every time that appears a '90' in formulas which deal with angles, e.g. `cos(radians(90))` would become `cos(radians(180 + 90))`). I preferred doing this only for the sake of giving a more general solution.

---

## Styling

We will render the points with a `Single symbol` and by recurring to one `Simple Marker` and three `Geometry generator` symbol layers:

[image]

In the further explanation, I will follow the same order of the symbols in the image above.

#### 1) Simple Marker

I chose a default symbol of a black star (this is the easier part of this tutorial), having a size of 3 mm and a width of 0.4 mm.

#### 2) Geometry Generator No. 1

Add a new symbol layer and select the `Geometry generator` type:

[image]

Insert this expression in the `Expression` field:

```
CASE
WHEN abs( "ALKUKULMA" - "LOPPUKULMA") < 360
THEN
make_line(
 $geometry,
 make_point(
  $x + 1000*cos(radians(90 - "ALKUKULMA")),
  $y + 1000*sin(radians(90 - "ALKUKULMA"))
  )
)
END
```

We have just defined the first line which points towards the point where the light sector starts from. This line is 1000 m long and it's created only when the opening angle of the sector light is not a round angle (this happens for avoiding that the line would break a whole circle).

#### 3) Geometry Generator No. 2

Same as above but, in this step, you need to use this expression:

```
CASE
WHEN abs( "ALKUKULMA" - "LOPPUKULMA") < 360
THEN
make_line(
 $geometry,
 make_point(
  $x + 1000*cos(radians(90 - "LOPPUKULMA")),
  $y + 1000*sin(radians(90 - "LOPPUKULMA"))
  )
)
END
```

We have just defined the first line which points towards the point where the light sector ends at. This line is 1000 m long and it's created only when the opening angle of the sector light is not a round angle (this happens for avoiding that the line would break a whole circle).

#### 4) Geometry Generator No. 3

Insert this expression in the `Expression` field:

```
CASE

WHEN abs("ALKUKULMA" - "LOPPUKULMA") <= 180 AND "ALKUKULMA" >= "LOPPUKULMA"
THEN
difference(
 boundary(
  buffer(
   $geometry, 900)
   ),
  make_polygon(
   geom_from_wkt(
    geom_to_wkt(
     make_line(
      $geometry,
      make_point($x + 2000*cos(radians(90 - "ALKUKULMA" )), $y + 2000*sin(radians((90 - "ALKUKULMA" )))),
      make_point($x + 2000*cos(radians(90 - ("LOPPUKULMA" + "ALKUKULMA")/2 )), $y + 2000*sin(radians((90 - ("LOPPUKULMA" + "ALKUKULMA")/2 )))),
      make_point($x + 2000*cos(radians(90 - "LOPPUKULMA")), $y + 2000*sin(radians((90 - "LOPPUKULMA")))),
      $geometry)
   )  
  )
 )
)

WHEN abs("ALKUKULMA" - "LOPPUKULMA") <= 180 AND "ALKUKULMA" <= "LOPPUKULMA"
THEN
intersection(
 boundary(
  buffer(
   $geometry, 900)
   ),
  make_polygon(
   geom_from_wkt(
    geom_to_wkt(
     make_line(
      $geometry,
      make_point($x + 2000*cos(radians(90 - "ALKUKULMA" )), $y + 2000*sin(radians((90 - "ALKUKULMA" )))),
      make_point($x + 2000*cos(radians(90 - ("LOPPUKULMA" + "ALKUKULMA")/2 )), $y + 2000*sin(radians((90 - ("LOPPUKULMA" + "ALKUKULMA")/2 )))),
      make_point($x + 2000*cos(radians(90 - "LOPPUKULMA")), $y + 2000*sin(radians((90 - "LOPPUKULMA")))),
      $geometry)
   )  
  )
 )
)

WHEN abs("ALKUKULMA" - "LOPPUKULMA") > 180 AND "ALKUKULMA" >= "LOPPUKULMA"
THEN
intersection(
 boundary(
  buffer(
   $geometry, 900)
   ),
  make_polygon(
   geom_from_wkt(
    geom_to_wkt(
     make_line(
      $geometry,
      make_point($x + 2000*cos(radians(90 - "ALKUKULMA" )), $y + 2000*sin(radians((90 - "ALKUKULMA" )))),
      make_point($x - 2000*cos(radians(90 - ("LOPPUKULMA" + "ALKUKULMA")/2 )), $y - 2000*sin(radians((90 - ("LOPPUKULMA" + "ALKUKULMA")/2 )))),
      make_point($x + 2000*cos(radians(90 - "LOPPUKULMA")), $y + 2000*sin(radians((90 - "LOPPUKULMA")))),
      $geometry)
   )  
  )
 )
)

WHEN abs("ALKUKULMA" - "LOPPUKULMA") > 180 AND "ALKUKULMA" <= "LOPPUKULMA"
THEN
difference(
 boundary(
  buffer(
   $geometry, 900)
   ),
  make_polygon(
   geom_from_wkt(
    geom_to_wkt(
     make_line(
      $geometry,
      make_point($x + 2000*cos(radians(90 - "ALKUKULMA" )), $y + 2000*sin(radians((90 - "ALKUKULMA" )))),
      make_point($x - 2000*cos(radians(90 - ("LOPPUKULMA" + "ALKUKULMA")/2 )), $y - 2000*sin(radians((90 - ("LOPPUKULMA" + "ALKUKULMA")/2 )))),
      make_point($x + 2000*cos(radians(90 - "LOPPUKULMA")), $y + 2000*sin(radians((90 - "LOPPUKULMA")))),
      $geometry)
   )  
  )
 )
)


END
```

We have just defined the arc between the starting and ending points of the light sector (please note that `2000` is an arbitrary value because I'm trying to create a *polygon* to intersect with the boundary of the circle having a radius of 900 m).

Furthermore, we need to set the color which is stored in the `"VARIS"` field. For doing this, we need to specify it with a custom expression. Follow the arrow in the image below:

[image]

and then type this expression after having clicked on the `Edit...` button:

```
CASE
WHEN  "VARIS" = 'vi' THEN color_rgb(51,160,44)
WHEN "VARIS" = 'v' THEN color_rgb(255,255,255)
WHEN "VARIS" = 'p' THEN color_rgb(227,26,28)
END
```

Please note that, for this symbol layer, I created two lines: the upper line defines the color to use (in fact I set the custom expression for this one), while the lower one is useful for defining a black border (it will have a width which is bigger than the one of the upper line). Remember also to set `Flat` as `Cap style` for both lines for avoiding any color overlapping.

---

## Labeling

#### 1) Setting the labels

Go to `Layer Properties` > `Labels` and, as usual, follow the red arrows:

[image]

and then type this expression:

```
CASE
WHEN "VARIS" = 'vi' THEN 'G'
WHEN "VARIS" = 'v' THEN 'W'
WHEN "VARIS" = 'p' THEN 'R'
END
```

We have just defined the color rule using the value stored in the `"VARIS"` field.

#### 2) Setting the placement for labels

Select the `Placement` option in the `Labels` Menu and select `Offset from point`.

Then, with reference to the image below:

[image]

follow the red arrow and type this expression:

```
CASE
WHEN "ALKUKULMA" > "LOPPUKULMA"
THEN
concat(
 -1000*cos(radians(90 - ("ALKUKULMA" + "LOPPUKULMA")/2)),
  ',',
  1000*sin(radians(90 - ("ALKUKULMA" + "LOPPUKULMA")/2))
)
WHEN "ALKUKULMA" <= "LOPPUKULMA"
THEN
concat(
 1000*cos(radians(90 - ("ALKUKULMA" + "LOPPUKULMA")/2)),
  ',',
  -1000*sin(radians(90 - ("ALKUKULMA" + "LOPPUKULMA")/2))
)
END
```

Then, follow the green arrow and type this expression:

```
CASE
WHEN "ALKUKULMA" >= "LOPPUKULMA"
THEN
180-(("ALKUKULMA" + "LOPPUKULMA")/2)
WHEN "ALKUKULMA" < "LOPPUKULMA"
THEN
- (("ALKUKULMA" + "LOPPUKULMA")/2)
END
```

## Final result

If you correctly performed the previous tasks, you should be able to get this result:

[image]

### Bonus

Since the minor parameters were too many for being completely covered within this answer, I have attached the style [here](http://pastebin.com/tUmbg7gj): you may open this code with any text editor and save it as a QGIS Layer Style file (i.e. with a `.qml` extension).

The above style was created using **QGIS 2.18.4** (it must have the same name of the shapefile you are using).

Comment: Looks great, really shows you the power of the geometry generator. Is it slow to render?

Comment: @Vesanto I tested it on one point having six features (i.e. six sector lights) and it rendered instantly. I think it should be fast also when dealing with hundreds of features because there's no call to providers or something similar, but only a couple of math operations and geometries as Well Know Text.

Comment: Questions/answers like these really show how versatile QGIS can be!

Comment: Looks great @mgri ! I am abroad without QGIS ome week now I will try your solutiom immediately when I get back!

Comment: @BenjaminDonner I'm sorry for the long answer, but I hope it will be enough for you! Let me know if it works or if you encounter any problem.

Comment: @mgri you are The Master, a fantastically good solution and a great explanation involving a lot of work, THANK YOU!!

Comment: @BenjaminDonner Thanks, I really appreciate! It was a nice challenge for me and I'm glad it worked also for you ;)

Comment: @mgri one problem, or perhaps should be described as two:

1. Your number 4 above: If the start angle "ALKUKULMA" is bigger than the end angle "LOPPUKULMA", then the light curve now shows between the end angle LOPPUKULMA and the start angle ALKUKULMA, not the opposite.  So for instance, ALKUKULMA (start angle) 174 and LOPPUKULMA 115 should show a colored curve going from 354 degrees to 295 degrees, (as south in this dataset is 0 degrees). The light cuurves are now created by the below, but I cannot find a way to alter this to get QGIS to understand to do the above change.

Comment: @mgri the problem two:
If a sector light goes from ALKUKULMA (start angle) 0 to LOPPUKULMA (end angle) 360, that means that the light shines in all directions. 
a) Right now, no arc / curve is created for such cases (no matter if I put the 180 + 90 in where 90 is present)
b) in these cases, the dotted line is superfluous, as it breaks a total circle. So a case / if agrument in your 2 and 3 above, which stops the dotted line from being made if the angle is 360 degrees, would be fantastic :)!

Thanks!
Benjamin

Comment: @BenjaminDonner For your first problem, do you want to draw an obtuse angle?

Comment: @mgri for ALKUKULMA/start angle 174 and LOPPUKULMA/end angle 115, here are how the sector should be (correct.png) and how it is now (incorrect.png): [image link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ckdbt9k232yxwzk/AABg5GiTZN0-KpXyg3O9DF2Za?dl=0)

Comment: @BenjaminDonner Thanks, I got it. The last thing: is there the possibility that ALKUKULMA and LOPPUKULMA  have the same angle value?

Comment: @mgri no I cannot find any such instance.

Comment: @BenjaminDonner Please, see the several edits in my answer. Everything should work by now: 1) creation of obtuse angle implemented; 2) creation of a whole circle when dealing with a round angle; 3) avoided the creation of dotted lines when dealing with round angles; 4) fixed the creation of proper labeling for any case. **I sincerely hope** that everything will work because I was very close to going **crazy**! =)

Comment: @mgri a mountain in this region should be named after you, thank you!! I have tested a bit and no problems with your added solutions have been found :)!

Comment: @BenjaminDonner I slightly changed the approach: the old one was good, but it only worked for specific cases; instead the last one should be more accurate (I couldn't ever have thinked about it without your feedbacks!). By now, I need holidays :)

Comment: I use this method and it works great. I have a nautical background and work as a digital cartographer and want to add some context to the 180 degree difference. This is done in nautical publications because the end user (navigators) use bearings to a point and not from a point because a bearing to can directly be used on a bearing device/compass when your navigating. I get my data from a collection of S-57 cells (layername=LIGHTS). I use the fieldcalc to make the 180 shift. This data is in WGS 84 without projection. I reprojected the layer to WGS 84 UTM 32 to make this symbology work.

Answer (score 2):

Very nice work indeed!

Just a short note that since 3.16 or so there is an expression 'wedge_buffer' which you can use in a geometry-generator (to create a wedge (black polygon) from a point layer (red dot)) as in:

[image: wedge buffer]

This is the result of generating a polygon using the following expression:

```
wedge_buffer(center:=$geometry,azimuth:=90,width:=60,outer_radius:=1000,inner_radius:=200)
```

where $geometry is the point geom, note azimuth, width, outer and inner radius are hardcoded here, but could come from fields of the layer