# Shifting display of overlapping lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, visualisation, qgis-custom-function

When points are overlapping, there is this property which allow to automatically display the lot of them separately around where they are, called 'Point displacement'. But it doesn't work for lines, even so it seems to me quite conceptually feasable in order to achieve something like that :

[image]

I absolutely need to see the differents lines which in reality are all in the same place (I am working in telecomunication networking). The only way I see for now is to really create different lines like in the picture above, thus creating spatial mistakes.

I'm using QGIS 2.14.

Comment: I think something could be done recurring to styling. Is the line in the middle the starting line? Then, I see that you created each one of the other lines by using three different geometries, so my question is if there are some specific additional rules from rendering them?

Comment: @mgri I am not sure to understand your question. The picture provided is an example in which I drew five different lines for the sake of demonstration. In reality it would be more that these 5 lines are in fact indeed on the spot of the middle one (they are wires, so all stuck in the same sheath).

Comment: You can render lines with a displacement ("offset") as well, but they would not meet at the start and end points.

Comment: @AndreJ Yes, and another problem would be that it would be quite manual operation where I would need something more automatic since it would be used by many users.

Comment: @GuiOmClair Following the attached image, I assumed that you start from one line which overlaps (for example) four other lines and that you need to find a way for displaying them separately, even if they overlap. I just said that it could be possible to reproduce what is displayed in the attached image without the needing of creating new geometries (but only recurring to style properties of the starting layer). Another way would be the one proposed by AndreJ, but it seems it doesn't fit to your needs.

Comment: @GuiOmClair Is it clearer by now? Am I right about your initial situation? If my solution would be of interest, I can try to help you, but I need to know if you start from one line geometry.

Comment: @mgri I am still not totally sure we understand each other. I have let's say 5 lines (so 5 different items, in the same layer since they would be wires) that are perfectly overlapping, and I would like to display them automatically in a way such as the picture above. I must say that I don't properly understand the solution you propose (I am not native english speaker so I have trouble figuring out what you mean by "recurring to style properties"), but your help is most welcome. :)

Comment: @GuiOmClair don't worry, I will surely try to help you in the next hours! (however, follow this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229961/creating-sector-lights-in-qgis/230989#230989) to understand the technique that I would try to apply for solving the issue).

Comment: @mgri Ok. I am looking on the thread you linked, and in order to precise, I must add that in my case it can be 2, 3, 4, 5 or more wires (although I think rarely more than 10) overlapping each other. So any solution would need to be flexible enough to adapt automatically to the variations in number. ;)

Comment: @GuiOmClair yes and I know it, but it should be a bit tricky thinking about the workflow. You will have my _2 cents_ as soon as I can if I find a solution!

Comment: As promised, here my _2 cents_. Please, let me know if you encounter any issue.

Answer (score 20):

I propose an approach that only recurs to a geometry generator and a custom function.

Before starting, I want to underline that I will focus the attention on the explanation of the minimal things to do for reproducing the desired result: this means that some other minor parameters (like sizes, widths and so on) should be easily adjusted by you for better fitting your needs.

Therefore, this solution works both for Geographic and Projected Reference Systems: in the following, I assumed to use a projected CRS (i.e. units of measurements are meters), but you can change them according to your CRS.

---

## Context

Let's assume to start from this linestring vector layer representing the wires (the labels represent the number of overlapping (coincident) wires):

[image]

---

## Solution

Firstly, go to `Layer Properties | Style` and then choose the `Single symbol` renderer.

From the `Symbol selector` dialog, choose a `Geometry generator` as symbol layer type and `Linestring / MultiLinestring` as geometry type. Then, click on the `Function Editor` tab:

[image]

Then, click on `New file` and type `draw_wires` as the name of the new function:

[image]

You will see that a new function has been created and it is listed on the left side of the dialog. Now, click on the name of the function and replace the default `@qgsfunction` with the following code (don't forget to add all the libraries attached here):

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from math import sin, cos, radians

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def draw_wires(angle, percentage, curr_feat, layer_name, feature, parent):

    def wires(polyline, new_angle, percentage):
        for x in range(0, len(polyline)-1):
            vertices = []
            first_point = polyline[x]
            second_point = polyline[x +1]
            seg = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([first_point, second_point])
            len_feat = seg.length()
            frac_len = percentage * len_feat
            limb = frac_len/cos(radians(new_angle))
            tmp_azim = first_point.azimuth(second_point)
            angle_1 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim+new_angle))
            dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_1), limb * sin(angle_1))
            point_1 = QgsPoint(first_point[0] + dist_x, first_point[1] + dist_y)
            angle_2 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim-new_angle))
            dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_2), limb * sin(angle_2))
            point_2 = QgsPoint(second_point[0] - dist_x, second_point[1] - dist_y)
            tmp_azim = second_point.azimuth(first_point)
            angle_3 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim+new_angle))
            dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_3), limb * sin(angle_3))
            point_3 = QgsPoint(second_point[0] + dist_x, second_point[1] + dist_y)
            angle_4 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim-new_angle))
            dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_4), limb * sin(angle_4))
            point_4 = QgsPoint(first_point[0] - dist_x, first_point[1] - dist_y)
            vertices.extend([first_point, point_1, point_2, second_point, point_3, point_4, first_point])
            tempGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(vertices)
            num.append(tempGeom)
        return num


    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    all_feats = {}
    index = QgsSpatialIndex()
    for ft in layer.getFeatures():
        index.insertFeature(ft)
        all_feats[ft.id()] = ft

    first = True

    tmp_geom = curr_feat.geometry()
    polyline = tmp_geom.asPolyline()
    idsList = index.intersects(tmp_geom.boundingBox())
    occurrences = 0
    for id in idsList:
        test_feat = all_feats[id]
        test_geom = test_feat.geometry()
        if tmp_geom.equals(test_geom):
            occurrences += 1
    if occurrences & 0x1:
        num = [tmp_geom]
    else:
        num = []

    rapp = occurrences/2
    i=2
    new_angle = angle

    while i <= occurrences:
        draw=wires(polyline, new_angle, percentage)
        i += 2
        new_angle -= new_angle/rapp
    first = True
    for h in num:
        if first:
            geom = QgsGeometry(h)
            first = False
        else:
            geom = geom.combine(h)
    return geom
```

Once you have done this, click on the `Load` button and you will be able to see the function from the `Custom` Menu of the `Expression` dialog.

Now, type this expression (see the image below as a reference):

```py
draw_wires(40, 0.3, $currentfeature, @layer_name)
```

[image]

You have just run a function which is saying, in an imaginary way:

> *"For the current layer (**@layer_name**) and the current feature (**$currentfeature**), display the wires together using an initial maximum opening of 40 degrees and with a change in direction at a distance of 0.3 times the length of the current segment."*

The only thing you need to change is the value of the first two parameters as you want, but obviously in a reasonable way (leave the other function parameters as provided).

Finally, click on the `Apply` button for applying the changes.

You will see something like this:

[image]

as expected.

---

**EDIT**

According to a specific request raised by the OP in a comment:

> *"Would it be possible to create this pattern only between the
>   beginning and the end of each polyline instead of between each
>   vertex?"*

I slightly edited the code. The following function should return the expected result:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from math import sin, cos, radians

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def draw_wires(angle, percentage, curr_feat, layer_name, feature, parent):

    def wires(polyline, new_angle, percentage):
        vertices = []
        len_feat = polyline.length()
        frac_len = percentage * len_feat
        limb = frac_len/cos(radians(new_angle))
        tmp_azim = first_point.azimuth(second_point)
        angle_1 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim+new_angle))
        dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_1), limb * sin(angle_1))
        point_1 = QgsPoint(first_point[0] + dist_x, first_point[1] + dist_y)
        angle_2 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim-new_angle))
        dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_2), limb * sin(angle_2))
        point_2 = QgsPoint(second_point[0] - dist_x, second_point[1] - dist_y)
        tmp_azim = second_point.azimuth(first_point)
        angle_3 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim+new_angle))
        dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_3), limb * sin(angle_3))
        point_3 = QgsPoint(second_point[0] + dist_x, second_point[1] + dist_y)
        angle_4 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim-new_angle))
        dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_4), limb * sin(angle_4))
        point_4 = QgsPoint(first_point[0] - dist_x, first_point[1] - dist_y)
        vertices.extend([first_point, point_1, point_2, second_point, point_3, point_4, first_point])
        tempGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(vertices)
        num.append(tempGeom)

    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    all_feats = {}
    index = QgsSpatialIndex()
    for ft in layer.getFeatures():
        index.insertFeature(ft)
        all_feats[ft.id()] = ft
    first = True
    tmp_geom = curr_feat.geometry()
    coords = tmp_geom.asMultiPolyline()
    if coords:
        new_coords = [QgsPoint(x, y) for x, y in z for z in coords]
    else:
        coords = tmp_geom.asPolyline()
        new_coords = [QgsPoint(x, y) for x, y in coords]
    first_point = new_coords[0]
    second_point = new_coords[-1]
    polyline=QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([first_point, second_point])
    idsList = index.intersects(tmp_geom.boundingBox())
    occurrences = 0
    for id in idsList:
        test_feat = all_feats[id]
        test_geom = test_feat.geometry()
        if tmp_geom.equals(test_geom):
            occurrences += 1
    if occurrences & 0x1:
        num = [polyline]
    else:
        num = []

    rapp = occurrences/2
    i=2
    new_angle = angle

    while i <= occurrences:
        draw=wires(polyline, new_angle, percentage)
        i += 2
        new_angle -= new_angle/rapp
    first = True
    for h in num:
        if first:
            geom = QgsGeometry(h)
            first = False
        else:
            geom = geom.combine(h)
    return geom
```

Comment: Wow! That's an impressive answer! Thank you very much for taking this time to find and share it. However : 1. I am having trouble applying it to my datas (when I apply the function, the lines disappear), but I guess the problem comes from my datas since it works on a temporary layer and 2. would it be possible to create this pattern only between the beginning and the end of each polyline instead of between each vertice?

Comment: @GuiOmClair the lines disappear because something goes wrong with the function. The problem doesn't come from the using of temporary layer, but it could be related to the using of MultiLine geometries instead of Line geometries. Please, load the layer in QGIS and then type these two lines in the Python Console: `layer=iface.activeLayer()` and then `print layer.wkbType()`. Click`Run`: which is the value of the printed number?

Comment: The number is 5 (what does it mean?)

Comment: @GuiOmClair It means that your layer is a MultiLineString layer, while I assumed it was a LineString layer (since you didn't specify it). This wouldn't be a problem and I will properly edit the code as soon as I can (maybe tomorrow). Furthermore, I should be able to render the wires only between the first and the last point of each (multi)line feature.

Comment: @GuiOmClair Since I need to set the percentage of the length from which changing the direction of wires (0.3 in my example), could it be ok for you if I measure the length as the distance between the first and the last point of the feature? Or you want to still measure the percentage as a fraction of the real length of the feature? The latter would change the result if you are working with arcs, but I imagine your features are nearly straight lines...

Comment: Yes, the features are straight lines (since they are generally easier to manage and export), so it would be better considering the real length of the wires.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58458/discussion-between-mgri-and-guiom-clair).

Comment: @GuiOmClair, see my edited answer. If it still doesn't work, please join the chat.

Comment: @GuiOmClair any news?

Comment: Yes, I sent some rather long messages on the chat, and see now the chat is not available. So I tried, it worked however still not like I would need. The last piece of code you added create the pattern between the first and last point, but without following the path of the original polyline. I guess in other words I would say that it needs to be indeed joining at the first and last point, but have some offset along the intermediary vertices.

Comment: That being said, and even if I think this is a feature that should exists in QGIS, the client said that finally it is better to actually draw the polylines separately since their GIS do not handle the situation the same way I thought to do (which was the spatially right way to do). So I won't be using this feature in my current project. I am sorry to say that now, after the time you spent working on the question.

Comment: @GuiOmClair sorry, I didn't notice it because I never received any notification from the chat. I thought my first solution was the best approach (in fact, it clearly reproduces the image you attached); then, I tried to follow your suggestion and it is still not enough for you; right now, I still don't understand what you are looking for. Probably, it would have been better if you reported a **clear graphical example** of the desired result because, as you said, I spent much time for nothing: take this as a suggestion for the next time.

Comment: @mgri Imagine 5 line features (bus routes) from the same layer. Each line travels the same route around a city, following the same roads. These 5 lines all overlap each other obviously. He wants to know how we can spread out the line symbols of each layer so that they don't overlap. And to do this without editing the data itself to shift the vertices apart.

Comment: This answer is somehow misleading form many, it only works for very simple overlapping lines. Since most real life data will have lines overlapping only on certain segments, this method is simply useless. since the geometry equality clause that determines the number of occurrences will always come up with a single occurrence at a time, and the shape will not be shifted. It is simply not doable on GIS software. Better results may be obtained with CAD software.

Answer (score 4):

Very nice work!

On the QGIS-users mailing list somebody  asked for the QGIS3 version of the functions.

I tried to rewrite them both (draw_wires for all vertices and draw_wires2 for only start/end).
They work for me (QGIS 3.20 here):

[image: both versions]

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from math import sin, cos, radians

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def draw_wires(angle, percentage, curr_feat, layer_name, feature, parent):

    def wires(polyline, new_angle, percentage, referenced_columns=[]):
        for x in range(0, len(polyline)-1):
            vertices = []
            first_point = polyline[x]
            second_point = polyline[x +1]
            #seg = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([first_point, second_point])
            seg = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([first_point, second_point])            
            len_feat = seg.length()
            frac_len = percentage * len_feat
            limb = frac_len/cos(radians(new_angle))
            tmp_azim = first_point.azimuth(second_point)
            angle_1 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim+new_angle))
            dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_1), limb * sin(angle_1))
            #point_1 = QgsPoint(first_point[0] + dist_x, first_point[1] + dist_y)
            point_1 = QgsPointXY(first_point[0] + dist_x, first_point[1] + dist_y)
            angle_2 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim-new_angle))
            dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_2), limb * sin(angle_2))
            #point_2 = QgsPoint(second_point[0] - dist_x, second_point[1] - dist_y)
            point_2 = QgsPointXY(second_point[0] - dist_x, second_point[1] - dist_y)
            tmp_azim = second_point.azimuth(first_point)
            angle_3 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim+new_angle))
            dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_3), limb * sin(angle_3))
            #point_3 = QgsPoint(second_point[0] + dist_x, second_point[1] + dist_y)
            point_3 = QgsPointXY(second_point[0] + dist_x, second_point[1] + dist_y)
            angle_4 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim-new_angle))
            dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_4), limb * sin(angle_4))
            #point_4 = QgsPoint(first_point[0] - dist_x, first_point[1] - dist_y)
            point_4 = QgsPointXY(first_point[0] - dist_x, first_point[1] - dist_y)
            vertices.extend([first_point, point_1, point_2, second_point, point_3, point_4, first_point])
            #tempGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(vertices)
            tempGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(vertices)
            num.append(tempGeom)
        return num

    #layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    all_feats = {}
    index = QgsSpatialIndex()
    for ft in layer.getFeatures():
        index.insertFeature(ft)
        all_feats[ft.id()] = ft

    first = True

    tmp_geom = curr_feat.geometry()
    polyline = tmp_geom.asPolyline()
    idsList = index.intersects(tmp_geom.boundingBox())
    occurrences = 0
    for id in idsList:
        test_feat = all_feats[id]
        test_geom = test_feat.geometry()
        if tmp_geom.equals(test_geom):
            occurrences += 1
    if occurrences & 0x1:
        num = [tmp_geom]
    else:
        num = []

    rapp = occurrences/2
    i=2
    new_angle = angle

    while i <= occurrences:
        draw=wires(polyline, new_angle, percentage)
        i += 2
        new_angle -= new_angle/rapp
    first = True
    for h in num:
        if first:
            geom = QgsGeometry(h)
            first = False
        else:
            geom = geom.combine(h)
    return geom
```

and

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from math import sin, cos, radians

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def draw_wires2(angle, percentage, curr_feat, layer_name, feature, parent):

    def wires2(polyline, new_angle, percentage):
        vertices = []
        len_feat = polyline.length()
        frac_len = percentage * len_feat
        limb = frac_len/cos(radians(new_angle))
        tmp_azim = first_point.azimuth(second_point)
        angle_1 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim+new_angle))
        dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_1), limb * sin(angle_1))
        #point_1 = QgsPoint(first_point[0] + dist_x, first_point[1] + dist_y)
        point_1 = QgsPointXY(first_point[0] + dist_x, first_point[1] + dist_y)
        angle_2 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim-new_angle))
        dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_2), limb * sin(angle_2))
        #point_2 = QgsPoint(second_point[0] - dist_x, second_point[1] - dist_y)
        point_2 = QgsPointXY(second_point[0] - dist_x, second_point[1] - dist_y)
        tmp_azim = second_point.azimuth(first_point)
        angle_3 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim+new_angle))
        dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_3), limb * sin(angle_3))
        #point_3 = QgsPoint(second_point[0] + dist_x, second_point[1] + dist_y)
        point_3 = QgsPointXY(second_point[0] + dist_x, second_point[1] + dist_y)        
        angle_4 = radians(90 - (tmp_azim-new_angle))
        dist_x, dist_y = (limb * cos(angle_4), limb * sin(angle_4))
        #point_4 = QgsPoint(first_point[0] - dist_x, first_point[1] - dist_y)
        point_4 = QgsPointXY(first_point[0] - dist_x, first_point[1] - dist_y)
        vertices.extend([first_point, point_1, point_2, second_point, point_3, point_4, first_point])
        #tempGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(vertices)
        tempGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(vertices)
        num.append(tempGeom)

    #layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    all_feats = {}
    index = QgsSpatialIndex()
    for ft in layer.getFeatures():
        index.insertFeature(ft)
        all_feats[ft.id()] = ft
    first = True
    tmp_geom = curr_feat.geometry()
    #coords = tmp_geom.asMultiPolyline()
    #if coords: 
    if tmp_geom.isMultipart():
        coords = tmp_geom.asMultiPolyline()
        new_coords = [QgsPointXY(x, y) for x, y in z for z in coords]
    else:
        coords = tmp_geom.asPolyline()
        new_coords = [QgsPointXY(x, y) for x, y in coords]
    first_point = new_coords[0]
    second_point = new_coords[-1]
    #polyline=QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([first_point, second_point])
    polyline=QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([first_point, second_point])
    idsList = index.intersects(tmp_geom.boundingBox())
    occurrences = 0
    for id in idsList:
        test_feat = all_feats[id]
        test_geom = test_feat.geometry()
        if tmp_geom.equals(test_geom):
            occurrences += 1
    if occurrences & 0x1:
        num = [polyline]
    else:
        num = []

    rapp = occurrences/2
    i=2
    new_angle = angle

    while i <= occurrences:
        draw=wires2(polyline, new_angle, percentage)
        i += 2
        new_angle -= new_angle/rapp
    first = True
    for h in num:
        if first:
            geom = QgsGeometry(h)
            first = False
        else:
            geom = geom.combine(h)
    return geom
```

Comment: Your code does not work!

Comment: @Beetroot that is very unhelpfull. WHAT does not work, Any messages?

Comment: @RichardDuivenvoorde In my case, your functions only work when the lines are exploded into segments. When I try to use these functions on _unexploded_ lines, it says "Expression is invalid" and on more info, it shows "Eval Error: name 'z' is not defined".