# Calling QGIS functions via Function Editor?

Tags: qgis, expression, qgis-custom-function

I am trying to write function in QGIS via function editor and the problem is to call QGIS built-in functions e.g. azimuth, centroid... etc. When I run my script, I get

```
'global name 'azimuth' is not defined'.
```

The same problem I got while I'm not specified module 'math' to function degree. My function code is on the picture:

[image: here is my function]

I imported different libraries, nevertheless function doesn't work.
Does anyone have any ideas how to call these functions?

Comment: Can you run the same "deg = math.degrees...." logic/statement within the QGIS python console without error?

Comment: No, the result is 'NameError: name 'math' is not defined'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run the built-in expressions as they are defined in the Field Calculator framework. This means that any expression like `azimuth`, `@geometry`, `centroid` and so on won't work if you try to use them when building a custom function.

Instead, you need to use the common PyQGIS syntax as you were writing a script from the Python Console or the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: Thanks!! I've found the majority of the Qgis expressions. But azimuth I' m not found yet anywhere

Comment: You may use `azim = first_point.azimuth(second_point)`, where `azim` is the azimuth value and `first_point` and `second_point` are QgsPoint objects. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239129/shifting-display-of-overlapping-lines-in-qgis/239370#239370) you will find another example  with the using of the azimuth function.