# Separating intersecting lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, overlapping-features, vertices, offset

I have a project in QGIS where multiple cables follow different paths using specific points as vertices, and sometimes the cables end up crossing over each other.

I would like to perform a displacement on the intersecting cables. One of the problems I encounter is ensuring that the displacement of one cable does not repeat in another.

Is it possible to identify the displacement that the surrounding cables have made and choose only one for each feature?

The following images demonstrate the current state of the cables and a simulation of what I want, which I created using styles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you read [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/375159/29431)?

Comment: Red and blue lines belong to the same layer or  different layers?

Comment: all the lines are in the same lane, infortune, the post can't help me

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data?